# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest: MaximumRetryCount and RetryIntervalSec are ignored

Tags: powershell, retry-logic, invoke-webrequest

I have a Powershell script that uses the `Invoke-WebRequest` command to make a Webservice request that returns an XML structure. I use the parameters `MaximumRetryCount` and `RetryIntervalSec` to handle any errors that might occur.

The call is embedded into a try/catch logic and looks as follows.

```
try {

    LogWrite "Download starts." 6;

    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output -MaximumRetryCount 10 -RetryIntervalSec 10
        
    }
catch {

    # writing the error message to the log
    exit;
}
```

Recently I found the following error in my log file:

```
05:00:01 HOSTNAME Download starts.
05:00:09 HOSTNAME An exception was caught: Invoke-WebRequest : No such host is known.At [REDACTED].ps1:xx char:2+     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output -MaximumRetryCount 1 ?+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Method: GET, Reques?PowerShell/7.3.6}:HttpRequestMessage) [Invoke-WebRequest], HttpRequestException /     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand /
```

As you can see there are only a few seconds between the first log message and the exception. Due to the parameters `MaximumRetryCount` and `RetryIntervalSec` I would have expected that the script performs several retries, but this obviously did not happen.

I am wondering why no retries were performed? I know that I could implement a retry logic on my own, but I would have expected that the retry-parameters take care of that?

I use Powershell version 7.3.9.

Comment: Most likely the server was down for maintenance and retry would not of solve issue.  You are making a connection and the timeout for connections are normally long like 30 seconds. Your error looks like connection completed and failed during the download. This is unusual. Some servers had limits on max size and you may of exceeded the limit and server closed the connection.  A webrequest is HTTP Protocol which uses TCP for the transport layer. The connection may be getting errors and TCP will close the connection if there is too many retries. TCP has a CRC for each Datagram and CRC may be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.4),

> MaximumRetryCount. Specifies how many times PowerShell retries a
> connection when a failure code between 400 and 599, inclusive or 304
> is received

So it only affects HTTP StatusCode responses and does nothing for other errors, like unknown host or when a network is down.

Comment: I see, so that implies that in my case a successfull HTTP connection was never established. And that case needs to be dealt with separately.